# Somar campo do tipo decimal entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Eu tenho uma tabela Conserto nela tenho ValorMaoObra, valorPeca e ValorTotal todos do tipo decimal. O campo ValorTotal = ValorMaoObra +  valorPeca. Porem esta retornando 0. Estou mostrando isso na View de detalhes quando eu clico vou ver o resumo do conserto com seu preço total.

Minha ConsertoController/detalhes

```
public ActionResult Detalhes(int id)
{
    decimal total = 0m;

    ConsertoVM model;
    using (Db db = new Db())
    {
        Conserto cons = db.Conserto.Find(id);
        decimal peca = cons.Pecas.ValorUnitatio;
        total += (cons.ValorMaoObra + peca);

        model = new ConsertoVM(cons);
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: não vi onde você está setando o valor no campo `ValorTotal` que você comentou na pergunta, só na variável `total`

Comment: Você não precisa fazer isso ai pode fazer direto na sua View se for só para somar um dado. o que tem dentro de ConsertoVM, tem como acessar os valores de Cons?

Comment: eu criei uma variavel total que recebe a soma de ValorUnitatio+ ValorMaoObra  e depois valor total  = total, mas no meu debug ta chegando zero

Comment: – Ricardo Pontual - era isso eu só criei a variavel total só pra ver se estava chegando o valor certo, porem ainda não estava atribuindo o valor pra variavel valorTotal, por isso tava mostrando 0, iniciante né haha vlw

Comment: Coloque essa operação na ConsertoVM! e busca o método na sua View! é simples assim, o que você está fazendo não vai funcionar

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta publicação porque era um pequeno erro que o AP já resolveu com a ajuda nos comentários.